# Using php config file to connect to database instead of PDO connection line

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following lines Of code for a database connection, however I would just want to use my include("config.php") Instead of this long line of code, how would i go about doing that

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lms;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'password');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('unable to connect to database ' . $e->getMessage());
}    

// create LM object, pass in PDO connection
$lm = new lazy_mofo($dbh);
```

Comment: Put those lines into your config.php. problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a config.php file, for example consider this file is stored in web root (`/var/www/`), then the contents of the config.php are like this:

```
<?php

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lms;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'password');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('unable to connect to database ' . $e->getMessage());
    }    

    // create LM object, pass in PDO connection
    $lm = new lazy_mofo($dbh);

?>
```

then in your other PHP scripts use the `include` function:

```
<?php

    include '/var/www/config.php';
    ...
```

Now in your PHP scripts you can access the `$lm` object and `$dbh` object.

Comment: Thing is I already have a Config file tht looks like this: <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('lms', $link);
?>

Comment: but the PDO is on a report I am working on so i got a template from a website and now i am trying to get all connections to run through one config file

Comment: so now my config file looks like this (and it seems to work):
 <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('lms', $link);
?>


<?php

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lms;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'password');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('unable to connect to database ' . $e->getMessage());
    }    

    // create LM object, pass in PDO connection
    $lm = new lazy_mofo($dbh);


?>

Comment: yeah using `include` is just like adding the lines from the included file into your PHP script.  Anything you put in the config.php file will get executed in the scripted where your `include` line occurs.

Comment: Thanks alot you have been very very helpful and I really appreciate

Comment: No problem best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

for example `include("config.inc.php")` and for the config.inc.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lms;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'password');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('unable to connect to database ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$lm = new lazy_mofo($dbh); 
?>
```

Comment: Not _or_. This is a PDO question - `mysql_*()` are not being used.

Comment: can someone explain what this line is/does `$lm = new lazy_mofo($dbh);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a db wrapper class in your include file and get really lazy about it =)

```
    define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'lms');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', 'password');

    class Database{

        public function __construct() {

            $db = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

    }

    $o = new Database();
```